# Create a Class whose object can not be created

Tags: java, class, object, access-modifiers

I am studying for my BS, and my professor has given me a task, he said: Create a class without using any access modifier or interface keyword whose object can't be created.

I went through Google but can't find the solution. How can this be done in Java?

Comment: Didn't the professor give you any further information to work with? Define "can not be created."

Comment: "I am a student of BS" English might not be your first language, but you should maybe know that has quite a funny interpretation: "I am a student of bullsh*t".

Comment: Constructors can throw exceptions

Comment: Do enums count as classes? `enum Foo {}`.

Comment: I don't know, but just professor said: create a class whose object can not be created without using any access-modifier

Comment: Would creating one with a syntactic error count as cheating? :-P In a similar manner you could also have a class with a statically instantiated member of something that *itself* can't be instantiated (resulting in a compile-time error, albeit syntactically correct), or have its constructor call a nonexistent method. Please don't take this too seriously.

Comment: Try a private default constructor

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Enums are classes ([JLS§8.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9)) that cannot be instantiated and cannot be subclassed; just create one without any values:

```
enum Foo {}
```

---

Other possibilities depending on interpretation:

[JonK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3419894/jonk) and [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) considered throwing an exception from the constructor:

```
final class Example {
    Example() {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

But [nick zoum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3133418/nick-zoum) pointed out that an instance is still created and exists, briefly, prior to the exception, even though it cannot (in the example above) be retained.

[nick zoum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3133418/nick-zoum) considered `abstract`:

```
abstract class Example {
}
```

...but [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) pointed out that `abstract` classes can be subclassed (they cannot be `final`), and a subclass instance "is a" superclass instance.

Comment: I think this is the only solution that actually does it. The JLS calls enums "[a special class type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9)" and thus they are classes. But you can't subclass them, you can't use `new` with them, and the only instances are their values. So an enum without values is a class that cannot be instantiated (other than possibly by manipulating bytecode, which I think any reasonable person can agree would be out of bounds).

Comment: @AndyTurner Feel free to add my answer to yours as instructed by TJCrowder

Comment: @nickzoum: Done. :-)

Comment: I think the throw exception in constructor is more likely the expected answer. That the instance briefly exists is an interesting side note, but not really relevant to anyone using the code.

Comment: Technically, enum classes can still be created using reflection

Comment: @FerryBig not true. As it says in [the language spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9), "Reflective instantiation of enum types is prohibited.".

Answer (score 6):

I'm not a Java person, but other answers gave me this idea:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;


class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Object o = new Problematic();

        // unreachable

    }
}

class Problematic
{
    static 
    {
        int i = 1 / 0 ;
    }
}
```

[Try it on ideone](http://ideone.com/dqZImW)

I'm pretty sure there's no way of making a `Problematic` and surviving...

(Note that when I tried `throw new Exception();` in the static initializer it wouldn't compile)

Comment: Basically a variant of the "throw Exception from Constructor" - idea, but on class-level instead of instance-level. And indeed, if you cannot initialize the class, you cannot create instances +1

Comment: `throw new RuntimeException();` should work in static initializers

Comment: @Kapep also gets "Main.java:20: error: initializer must be able to complete normally", the same as `Exception`

Comment: @AakashM Nice, I didn't know that [static initializers can't just always throw or even use `return`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13532794/897024). I just tried `if (true) throw new RuntimeException();` which works fine though, so the checks don't seem very thorough.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the keyword `abstract`?

For example:

```
abstract class Test{}
```

Of course this can be overwritten, so please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40234558/create-a-class-whose-object-can-not-be-created/40234675#40234675) for a more foolproof design.

Comment: I can create one of those, via a subclass. Remember, even a subclass instance "is a" `Test`.

Comment: Make it final abstract, Final means cannot be subclassed, abstract = cannot be instantiated

Comment: @TheresaForster yeah, try it!

Comment: @TheresaForster: A `final abstract` class will not compile.

Comment: @TheresaForster `final` and `abstract` are mutually exclusive keywords - it won't compile if you use them both

Comment: A class is not allowed to be both.

Comment: Well the task is one that does not make sense, Make a class you cannot instantiate, The obvious answer is Abstract, but a subclass is not instanceof Test but it is a child of Test so can be cast to Test, however a final constructor may stop subclassing so abstract class with final constructor?

Comment: @TheresaForster: *"...but a subclass is not instanceof Test..."* Yes, it is.

Comment: @TheresaForster `new Test() {} instanceof Test` is true. Using `abstract` is simply not a valid answer to this question.

Comment: @TheresaForster so you are telling me a `goldfish` is not a `fish`?

Comment: I see someone's downvoted this. Frankly I think that's harsh, the question is really open-ended. `abstract` could be a valid answer, depending on one's interpretation.

Comment: @nickzoum: I think we should copy our answers into Andy's as examples of things that come close, depending on interpretation, but don't quite make it.

Comment: without any access modifier

Comment: @user3847788 As stated in the answer, please see the answer provided by Andy Turner

Answer (score 0):

**Anonymous inner class** should be the answer.

**Example:**

```
public abstract class HelloWorld{
    abstract void x();
    public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Hello World"); 
        HelloWorld h = new HelloWorld(){
            void x(){
                System.out.println(" ");
            }
        }; 
        h.x(); 
    } 
}
```

A class is created, but it's name is decided by the compiler which extends the `HelloWorld` class and provides the implementation of the `x()` method.

Comment: To make this a useful answer, you should show some code which does this.

Comment: public abstract class HelloWorld{
abstract void x();
     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        HelloWorld h=new HelloWorld(){void x(){System.out.println("  ");}};
        h.x();
     }
}

Comment: Here A class is created but its name is decided by the compiler which extends the HelloWorld class and provides the implementation of the x() method.

Answer (score 0):

Without hearing exactly how your professor phrased it, "without using any access-modifier" might mean they are attempting to teach you how the "default" access modifier works?

In which case:

```
package mypackage.nocreate;
class MyClass {
}
```

And then:

```
package mypackage;
import mypackage.nocreate.MyClass;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyClass();   // not allowed - in a different package
    }
}
```

You could argue that - in the source code at least - that doesn't use any access modifier :)

Comment: I think the "acces-modifer" constraint is here to prevent using a private constructor on a final class.